# PyScript: connecting to a Postgres database?

Tags: python, postgresql, pyscript

I'm testing `PyScript` for the purposes of submitting queries to a Postgres database, creating `Pandas` dataframes, and rendering some numerical results and visualizations in the browser.

I'm attempting to connect to a `Postgres` database hosted on Heroku.

My code is as follows:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.4.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-2.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@holoviz/panel@0.13.1/dist/panel.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>

        <title>PyScript Demo</title>
        <py-env>
            - pandas
            - panel
            - psycopg2
        </py-env>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='output' class="text-3xl text-center"></div>
        <button id="retrieve-data" class="mt-4 p-2 text-white bg-blue-600 rounded" pys-onClick="retrieve_data">Get Data</button>
        <py-script src="./main.py"></py-script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.py**

```
import panel as pn
import psycopg2 as pg

pn.extension()

connection = pg.connect(host="ec2-12-345-678-910.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
                        port = 5432,
                        database="test_db",
                        user="test_user",
                        password="my_password_here")


var_1 = 'a test string...'
pyscript.write('output', var_1)

def retrieve_data(*args):
    pyscript.write('output', 'Foo')
```

In the web browser, I see the standard messages:

```
Loading runtime...
Runtime created...
Initializing components...
```

However, the page fails to load.

Is it possible to connect to `Postgres` using `PyScript`?

Comment: I don't think this is recommended (at least not publicly) because the HTTP server will host the Python script, which will include your database path and credentials for anyone to publicly see. Thus why a RESTful / GraphQL API would be better.

Comment: But to answer your question, you never are using `connection` variable, so what output did you expect?

Comment: @OneCricketeer -- minimally, I would expect the page to finish loading.  It doesn't.  It's as though it's trying to establish the connection, but can't.

Comment: That's entirely possible. You could wrap the connection variable in a try-except to test that theory

Comment: For PyScript always catch exceptions. Otherwise, your Python code will stop running at the line that threw an exception. You cannot use Python packages that rely upon the Socket API. That API does not exist in browsers. If a package depends on the **requests** package, it will not work in the browser.